# NPE in spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm doing a batch job by using spark, and programming in scala.  The job is an simple class.  However, I defined a field variable for the class which is then used in the job running methods.

The field variable is initialized before the real dataframe and RDD operations, but is later used when working with RDD.

What I've observed is, in my local development environment which has only one spark worker, everything works fine.  However, when I submitted the job to a spark cluster, it failed and said the field var is a NULL.

Then I think, the field var is not correctly serialized.  Is this true?

A follow up question is, when doing the spark job, is it recommended to use field variables?  Is there design pattern?

**Edit**

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class Test {
  var config : MyConfig = null.asInstanceOf[MyConfig]
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    config = new MyConfig

  }

  def job() = {
    /*config is null here*/
  }
}

case class MyConfig(
                     var from: String = "",
                     var to: String = "",
                     var unit: String = "",
                     var ids: Seq[String] = new mutable.ArraySeq[String](0)
                   ) {
  override def toString: String = {
    val sb = new StringBuilder
    sb.append(
      "from[%s], to[%s], last_n_unit[%s], id[%s]".format(
        this.from,
        this.to,
        this.unit,
        this.ids.mkString(",")
      )
    )
    sb.toString
  }
}
```

Comment: > Then I think, the field var is not correctly serialized. Is this true? --
Can be, difficult to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Please read about [mcve].

Comment: This code doesn't really say much, other than that you're abusing a case class.

Comment: @Jasper-M, thanks!  I'll update my code.  However, why do you think it's abusing a case class?  How to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is initialized, but when the class is instantiated on the remote worker, it is null again. Make your variable a member of the new function you are defining and this must solve the problem.